# Как в виндовс можно взаимодействовать со звуком фонового окна?

Tags: winforms, аудио, framework

Хочу повлиять на  "отключение" звука из оконного приложения которое переходит в фон (альт таб). Готовые решения? советы по алгоритму\библиотеке?

Comment: Думаю, единого способа нет. Зависит от технологии/платформы, использованной для написания приложения и прочих факторов.

Comment: Но ведь виндовс использует единую видновс.форм, может какие-нть винапи могут дать мне контроль над ситуацией? @alexanderpetrov

Comment: я не особо шарю в теме и даже не представляю какие инструменты доступны для решения задачи

Comment: Да, с помощью WinAPI можно послать сообщение в то окно. Но приложение должно принимать эти сообщения и обрабатывать. А если оно не использует их, то...

Comment: ладно. давайте по порядку. как мне провести диагностику этого ПО? как я могу узнать на чем он написан, какие вообще аналитические данные мне доступны? вы знаете, просто когда я хочу начать изучать программирование, то ютуб мне предлагает написать калькулятор и не способен отвечать на вопросы, которые у меня вызывают интерес. быть может тут я могу найти людей, которые могут меня направить\помочь правильными советами?

Comment: Не задавайте вопросы в комментариях. Их никто не увидит. Или отредактируйте вопрос, или задайте новый.